# POST form React to express API using useEffect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, express

I'm not really experienced. I'm trying to post a form when clicking on submit from a react component to my express api using useEffect. Here is what I did :

this is my react component

```
export function AdminFields () {

    const[vehiclesList, addVehicles] = useState([{}])

    useEffect(() => {
        const addVehicles = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'New car' })
        };
        fetch('"http://localhost:5000/cars"', addVehicles)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => addVehicles(data));
    


    }
  
    )
    async function vehiclesList(){
        const { data } = await Axios.post(
            'http://localhost:5000/cars',
            vehiclesList
          )
          addVehicles(data)
    }
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        fetchData()
      }



    return(
            <div classname="Fields" method='POST' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h2>Ajout d'un véhicule</h2>
            <br />
            <div classname="input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nom du propriétaire" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div classname="input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="N° immatriculation" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div classname="input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Marque" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div classname="input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Couleur" />
            </div>
            <br /> 
            <ValidateAdminButton type='submit'>Valider</ValidateAdminButton>
             
        </div>
);
}
```

```
I tried to add small pieces of code I could understand from other post.
```

My express api is running on the port 5000,please help me

Comment: Where is `fetchData()` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting code you have going on here. It appears you have some slight problems with the naming of your variables.

You use the same identifier, `addVehicles` for two completely different things. First of all, your state mutator is called `addVehicles`, but then in the context of your `useEffect` function you override your state mutator by calling it `addVehicles` as well.

Within the context of your `useEffect` your `addVehicles` identifier points to your request options and not the state mutator function as you would expect.

I would suggest renaming the variable that holds your http request options. You might also find it useful to name the state mutator that modifies the state variable, `vehiclesList`, to `setVehiclesList` -- as tends to be the convention. In general, you might have `const [var, setVar] = useState(initialValue)`, where `var` can be replaced with any piece of state you intend to have.

Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: Thank you, I changed my file with your advices with the correct request on my express project. Now it works!

Comment: That's great! Could you please give me a thank you upvote :D?